# using ajax beforeSend to modify data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let's say I have an Ajax call from jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: myUrl,
   data: myData,
   type:'post'
});
```

I would like to be able to add to the myData using

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   beforeSend: function(call){...}
});
```

The result should be that all ajax calls (both post and get) is modified so if i get an extra parameter IsAjax=true

Comment: you cant edit the variable before putting it into the ajax call?

Comment: You could, but that wouldn't be very DRY.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2131-Using-jQuery-ajaxSetup-To-Accumulate-Global-Data-Parameters-For-AJAX-Requests.htm) explains how you can use `$.ajaxSetup` to add data.  It accumulates like `$.extend`
Just do this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  data:{
    isAjax:true
  }
});
```

Comment: if you are using function instead of 'true' this doesn't work.   ex:  isAjax:getValue()

Answer (score 30):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
    settings.data = $.extend(settings.data, {isAjax: true});
    return true;
  }
});
```

==== UPDATE ====

> When `data` is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the
> object's key/value pairs unless the `processData` option is set to
> `false`. For example, `{ a: "bc", d: "e,f" }` is converted to the
> string `"a=bc&d=e%2Cf"`. If the value is an array, jQuery serializes
> multiple values with same key based on the value of the `traditional`
> setting (described below). For example, `{ a: [1,2] }` becomes the
> string `"a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2"` with the default `traditional: false`
> setting.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

As you can see, the setting **processData** should to be **false**. So it can be setted when you do request in `$.ajax()` or globally in `$.ajaxSetup()`.

Comment: 1) you don't need to return true (just don't return false)
2) I think at this point, data has already become a parameterized string, so you'd need to append &isAjax=true to it (since it's no longer an object that can be extended).

Comment: 1) It's a good habit to make return in case it affects the functionality. 2) I think it depends of which format of data you pass in **ajax** function

Comment: 1) Ok, but in the case of this particular function, it doesn't affect the functionality, so it's still not necessary.  Not all functions need to return anything (that's why stricter languages define certain functions as "void").
2) I don't think it matters what format it was (get or post, data obj/string).  data passed as a native object still logs as  a parameterized string within this function.

Comment: Just confirming that `settings.data` has indeed been serialized by this point. I just tested it.

Comment: What can I do to add data before it is serialized?

Comment: @mpen, @Shad Using `processData: false` will preserve data as object in `beforeSend` function too. So you can use `$.extend(settings.data, {isAjax: true})` or something like this.

Answer (score 9):

You can just actually use beforeSend in $.ajax();

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    this.data += '&' + $.param({
      param: 'test'
    });
  }
});
```