# Mark a form submission as ajax by adding parameters to POST after submit

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I tried the solution in this post - [using ajax beforeSend to modify data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521594/using-ajax-beforesend-to-modify-data) - but the parameters passed do not include the isAjax key.

The solution given:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  data:{
    isAjax:true
  }
});
```

This is my CoffeeScript:

```
$.fn.related_table = (table,focus)->
  $(this).submit ->
    $.ajaxSetup data:
      isAjax: true
    fs = $(this).serializeArray()
    row = build_output fs
    $("#{table} > tbody:last").append(row)
    $(table).toggle(true)
    $.ajax( 
      data: fs
      type: "POST"
      cache: false
      dataType: "json"
      success : (res, status, xhr) => [
        $("#{table} tr.pending").addClass("success"),
        anim_success("#{table} > tbody > tr.pending > td.saved:last-of-type"),
        $(this)[0].reset() ]
      error : (xhr, status, err) => [
        $("#{table} tr:last-of-type").addClass("error"),
        anim_error("#{table} > tbody > tr.pending > td.saved:last-of-type") ]
      complete : (xhr, status) => [
        $("#{table} tr.pending").removeClass("pending"),
        $("#spinning_wheel").hide(),
        $("*[autofocus]:first").focus()]
    )
    false
```

You can see I've added the `ajaxSetup` within the submit handler in order to try and make sure it's not a context issue, but I've tried it elsewhere too. The function works fine without the modification (and even with it) in that it submits the data, it's just it doesn't add or send the extra parameter.

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript/CoffeeScript/jQuery. How can I achieve this?

jQuery version is 1.8.16.

---

I tried several different ways to get this to work, but was unable to. I've set up a repo on GitHub with a simple site to test this, if anyone wishes to use it https://github.com/yb66/Stackoverflow-question-9337273.

Luckily, I found Sinatra has a helper method `request.xhr?` that I can use instead of what I was trying to do, but I can still see this would be helpful so I'll leave the question open.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you set `url` in your $.ajax call, otherwise it seems OK.

This works as expected, see this jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/t6Yn7/

If you change the line that reads:

```
json: '{"my": "cat"}'
```

to something else, e.g.:

```
jsonXXX: '{"my": "cat"}'
```

you will see that the one from the ajaxSetup at the top, i.e.:

```
json: '{"hello": "world"}'
```

gets picked up as expected.

Try this example locally and if it works, first convert this working example to CoffeeScript, then proceed with building on top of it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found that if I didn't set the url it takes the form's one or uses the current url, and I've set separate get and post handlers in my app, it's quite helpful! Aside from that, I still can't get this to work and I'm trying to debug the script, but I'm finding it difficult to get the state of the jquery objects involved, I'd like to see what the state of `data` is at different points, but I'll keep trying and see what I find. Thanks.

Comment: OK, makes sense - did you try to use the same thing I put in the jsFiddle and get that working locally in JS only? As it works on jsFiddle, it should work for you without any modifications. You may also want to take a look at the `beforeSend` - if you use Firefox, you can `console.log` it and some more info that might help debugging.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying. Finally got back around to trying to solve this and couldn't, it clobbers the data in ajaxSetup each time. I found a different way to do what I wanted but will leave the question open and added some notes above in case anyone else needs them. Thanks for the help though, it's much appreciated.